# Nested for loop comparing files

Tags: bash, loops, grep

I am trying to write a bash script that looks at two files with the same name, each in a different directory.

I know this can be done with diff -r, however, I would like to take everything that is in the second file that is not in the first file and output it into an new file (also with the same file name)

I have written a (nested) loop with a grep command but it's not good and gives back a syntax error:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/Path/dir1/*
FILES2=/Path/dir2/*

for f in $FILES
do
for i in $FILES2
do 
if $f = $i
grep -vf $i $f > /Path/dir3/$i

done
done
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Path/dir1/
for f in *; do
    comm -13 <(sort $f) <(sort /Path/dir2/$f) > /Path/dir3/$f
done
```

if syntax in shell is

```
if test_command;then commands;fi
```

commands are executed if test_command exit code is 0

```
if [ $f = $i ] ; then  grep ... ; fi
```

but in your case it will be more efficient to get the file name

```
for i in $FILES; do
    f=/Path/dir2/`basename $i`
    grep
done
```

finally, maybe this will be more efficient than grep -v

```
comm -13 <(sort $f) <(sort $i)
```

comm -13 will get everything which is in the second and not in first ; comm without arguments generates 3 columns of output : first is only in first, second only in second and third what is common.
-13 or -1 -3 removes first and third column

Comment: lovely, this has worked I am sticking with it but thanks to everyone I appreciate all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR1=/Path/dir1
DIR2=/Path/dir2
DIR3=/Path/dir3

for f in $DIR1/*
do
  for i in $DIR2/*
  do 
    if [ "$(basename $f)" = "$(basename $i)" ]
    then
      grep -vf "$i" "$f" > "$DIR3/$(basename $i)"
    fi
  done
done
```

Comment: Thank you, have tried this because it is closest to my original and therefore more understandable for me ;)
It did not work in it's basic form, then I realised the baseline name is the key so I've changed it to:
`code` #!/bin/bash
`code`DIR1=/Path1/
`code`DIR2=/Path2/
`code`DIR3=/Path3/

`code` for f in $DIR1/*
`code` do
`code` for i in $DIR2/*
 `code` do 
 `code`   if [ "$DIR1/$(basename $f)" = "$DIR2/$(basename $i)" ]
    then
      grep -vf "$i" "$f" > "$DIR3/$(basename $i)"
    fi
`code`  done
`code`done

however I still have no output, not sure what I am doing.

Comment: Ohhh, I just realized what it is.  In the loop, `$f` ends up being `/Path/dir1/<file>` and `$i` ends up being `/Path/dir2/<file>`, so of course the two aren't equal.  I fixed it, try it again.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to say. Your edit works beautifully. I have used the solution by @Nahuel Fouilleul only because the output is already sorted for me!

Answer (score 0):

This assumes no special characters in filenames.  (eg, whitespace.  Use double quotes if that is unacceptable.):

```
a=/path/dir1
b=/path/dir2
for i in $a/*; do test -e $b/${i##*/} && 
   diff $i $b/${i##*/} | sed -n '/^< /s///p'; done
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting no outputs which is very strange. There are definitely different (and similar) lines in the files as I had started to do this manually. I'm not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: @jksl  Minor edit: use `##` instead of `#` to trim the leading path.